# If $f(x)$ is irreducible in $ \mathbb z [ x]$ , then for all primes $p$ the reduction $f'(x)$ of $f(x)$ modulo $p$ is irreducible in $F_p[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

If  $f(x)$     is irreducible in  $ \mathbb z [ x]$    , then for  all primes  $p$ the reduction   $f'(x)$           of    $f(x)$     modulo  $p$ is irreducible in      $F_p[x]$.

Is the statement true? Can anyone give me a hint?

My attempt : I think the statement is  not true.

$x^2+4x+5$ is irreducible in $\mathbb z[x]$ But so is not in $F_2[x]$.

Am I right? Can anyone please tell me on what more conditions the statement will be true?

Comment: Is that a statement or a question?

Comment: $f(x)=2x+1$ is irreducible over the integers, but $\overline{f'(x)}=\overline{2}= \overline{0}$ is not irreducible in $F_2[x]$.

Comment: I think $f’$ here has no relationship with the derivative of $f$, it is just a notation for the reduction.

Answer (score 1):

This is false: for instance $1+X^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ but not in $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$, because there $1+X^2=(1+X)^2$.